# Possible to monitor when an image is being added/removed from a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

If it's possible to somehow monitor a change in a div's DOM then that would be my solution - that will be enough to fire my event handler, but in case that's not possible - this is my problem:

I have a div, some javascript function (out of my control) will add or remove an image to this div (potentially nested in several divs/spans).

I need to attach an event (if possible using jQuery) that will fire when this particular image is added or not.

EDIT: To clarify - when  I say added - I don't mean some sort of toggle of it's display attribute, I mean literally completely added or completely removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *mutation events* for that purpose. Be aware that some of those events are deprecated by now.

```
$('div').on( 'DOMSubtreeModified', function( event ) {
   // something was changed
});
```

If you just need to know if some node was added, use

```
$('div').on( 'DOMNodeInserted', function( event ) {
   // something was changed
});
```

The `event object` will give you further information about what exactly happend.

---

Since you asked for an alternative, there is the jQuery `livequery` plugin. AFAIK, i'll also use the *Mutation Events* if available, but it claims to be compatible with all browsers jQuery supports. That means, they will use a fallback solution (most likely `intervall timers`) to check for changes in incompatible browsers.

Further read: [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy, looks spot on. I'm a bit concerned when you say some events are deprecated tho - what's the impact of that? Thanks again, +1.

Comment: I think DOMNodeInserted will not work in IE, and there may be no exact equivalent for it in IE. Not sure about webkit

Comment: @DeeMac: well, W3C says that the implementation of those events is flawed and its getting replaced, "some day", with another similar mechanism. Furthermore, IE might have some troubles with those events, but otherwise those events are well supported by now. I suggest you to read the MDN and the spec tho.

Comment: @jAndy - hmm ok. Thanks again for pointing that out. I'm dubious about using this, it's quite a key part in the page it'll be playing and I can't afford it to fail really. Do you know of any alternatives? I've looked in jQuery's .live() but jQuery site itself says to avoid it!?

Comment: I know of another alternative in the form of a timer, but I definitely want to avoid that.

Comment: @DeeMac: yes, there is a plugin called `livequery`. I'll updated the answer for that.

Comment: Don't use mutation events. They are gradually being removed from supportive browsers, and were never supported in IE at all.

Comment: @Geuis: thats bad advice. Beside IE (IE9 btw starts to support those events aswell FYI), it works pretty well across browsers. And, they will never get removed, but replaced with a very similar API. So its totally cool to use.

Comment: @jAndy - marked as answer. Thanks for your help mate. I've just solved it another way in case you were wondering (boss is not allowing plug-ins on this project) - fortunately enough the blur event of the span that has image inserted after it is triggered so I'll handle that instead.

Comment: @jAndy "Cool" is irrelevant. What matters is that there are practical drawbacks to Mutation Events, which are described at MDN. Another problem not mentioned there is that there is no reliable way to test whether Mutation Events are supported (an implementation may not throw an exception with `createEvent(…)` but still do not support them). Given that, the timer-observer pattern, which is at least known to be cross-browser, appears to be the logical course of action here.

Comment: @jAndy I was mistaken about IE support, true. But my advice stays the same. The first thing it says on the MDN page is *not* to use mutation events. Also says that IE9 doesn't implement them correctly. Its a leaky, creaky ship and best to stay away from.

Comment: @Geuis: my argument stays also the same. MDN also says, that MutationEvents are going to get replaced by a *very* similar thing. So it'll be *very* easy to adapt. And also, it works well in most browsers even nowadays.

Comment: How are you going to notice the change? You cannot even find out reliably if they are supported right now.